# Batch File - Why set variable inside Foreach break the loop?

Tags: batch-file

i have a problem. Here my code:

```
set listPath=1 2  
for %%n in (%listPath%) do ( 
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    IF "!ver!"=="" (
        :loop
        echo Insert Version:
        set /p "ver="
        IF "!ver!"=="" ( 
            echo Invalid!
            Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
            goto loop
        ) ELSE (
            goto Next
        )
        :Next
    )
    echo ver: !ver!
    pause > nul
)
```

Because it does not work? Each time I execute the first loop and then exit the foreach ending the execution. If, on the other hand, I omit the set / p everything works normally and cycles the set well. Why? How can I go about putting that user input into the loop without breaking the loop? Thanks

Comment: 1. because you are using `goto` inside a loop. Don't do that. change to `call` and 2, Your `:next` label is also not valid. the first action for it is `)` and that is seen as an invalid command. 3. Your `if` `else` statements are not in balance. have a look at `if /?` from `cmd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things for yourself, let me show you why I say that:

the `choice` command will force you to only select one of the options. It does not allow any other choices, other than what is in the list:

```
@echo off
choice /c 12 /m "Select version"
echo Ver: %errorlevel%
```

You already have the `%errorlevel%` variable which you can use to reflect as version, but you can assign that to your `ver` variable, if you really wanted as well:

```
@echo off
choice /c 12 /m "Select version"
set "ver=%errorlevel%"
echo Ver: %ver%
```

Other than making it that simple, your current code has numerous issues.

1. You do not have your `if` and `else` statements correctly formatted. run from `cmd` `if /?` to see the correct syntax.
2. You cannot `goto` inside of a `for` loop parenthesized block
3. Your label position is invalid. the first command it sees after label is `)` which is an invalid command.
4. The `for` loop is not even needed and makes no sense to be honest.

If you however wanted to still use your overcomplicated version, then this will be a better version:

```
@echo off
set "listPath=1 2"
set ver=
:loop
set /p "ver=Insert Version: "
if not %ver% equ 1 if not %ver% equ 2 (
  echo Invalid!
  Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
  goto :loop
)
echo ver: %ver%
pause>nul
```